# re-index array and add totals

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to figure out how to restructure an array and total values by given keys. I currently have an array called `$data` that is returning this result:

```
Bill => array:3 [▼
  "01" => array:6 [▼
    "Food " => array:2 [▶]
      hamburger=>array:[
        sales=> 210.00
        purchases=>200.00
      ]
      burrito=>array:[
        sales=> 100.00
        purchases=>40.00
      ]
    "Drink     " => array:2 [▶]
      coke=>array:[
        sales=> 210.00
        purchases=>200.00
      ]
      pepsi=>array:[
        sales=> 100.00
        purchases=>40.00
      ]
    "total" => array:7 [▶]
      sales=>620.00
      purchases=>480.00
  ]
]
Ted => array:3 [▼
  "01" => array:6 [▼
    "Food " => array:2 [▶]
      hamburger=>array:[
        sales=> 110.00
        purchases=>100.00
      ]
      burrito=>array:[
        sales=> 120.00
        purchases=>40.00
      ]
    "Drink     " => array:2 [▶]
      coke=>array:[
        sales=> 110.00
        purchases=>100.00
      ]
      pepsi=>array:[
        sales=> 120.00
        purchases=>40.00
      ]
    "total" => array:7 [▶]
      sales=>460.00
      purchases=>280.00
  ]
]
```

My issue is that I need to fit this into a laravel blade that is not concerned with bill or ted, but rather totals for everyone. Where the existing keys are "Bill" and "Ted", I would need the new structure to actually be identified by the "01", but I want to total all of the categories within that level. So I would be hoping to get results like this:

```
"01" =>[▼
  "Food " => array:2 [▶]
    hamburger=>array:[
      sales=> 320.00
      purchases=>300.00
    ]
    burrito=>array:[
      sales=> 220.00
      purchases=>140.00
    ]
  "Drink     " => array:2 [▶]
    coke=>array:[
      sales=> 320.00
      purchases=>300.00
    ]
    pepsi=>array:[
      sales=> 220.00
      purchases=>80.00
    ]
  "total" => array:7 [▶]
    sales=>1080.00
    purchases=>760.00
 ]
```

I can easily loop on this like:

```
foreach($data as $key=> $value){
  foreach($value as $categoryNumber => $categories){
    foreach($categories as $categoryDetails => $details){
  
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm completely stuck as to how to re-structure this and total by the new indices

Comment: It's rather straightforward. Create a new array to hold the result. Take the current loop key, if it doesn't exist create it in the result and copy the value, otherwise just add the value to the existing one.

Comment: use collect. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections , cant be bothered doing it for you since you did not even provide the raw data and i dont want to format it.

Comment: @michael_mano I'm not necessarily asking for anyone to "do it for me", I'm just not sure of exactly how to go about it, whether In laravel or not (I'm newer to php regardless). Also, I dumped the raw data and tried to get it formatted properly in my text editor but I'll take another stab at it

Comment: here is a `var_export`, think its right, had to build the array by hand, https://kopy.io/aWt1W  .. and yes the Collection methods are your friends

Comment: @lagbox thank you for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you arrived at the above `dd();`, I am sure there is a better way of collecting these totals prior to arriving here. But now that you are here (say, you received this via an API or whatever), this would make the totals as you mentioned:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($input as $i) {
    foreach ($i as $group => $n) {
        if (!array_key_exists($group, $result)) $result[$group] = [];
        foreach ($n as $category_name => $category) {
            if (!array_key_exists($category_name, $result[$group])) $result[$group][$category_name] = [];
            foreach ($category as $item_name => $item) {
                if (!array_key_exists($item_name, $result[$group][$category_name])) {
                    $result[$group][$category_name][$item_name] = $item;
                } else {
                    foreach ($item as $purpose => $dollars) {
                        $result[$group][$category_name][$item_name][$purpose] += $dollars;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In each step, I am checking if the array key exists, and if not, creating it. If you ignore those [array_key_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) checks, you'll see that I am simply copying the contents over and summing where necessary.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! Indeed I am using an API otherwise I would restructure the data internally

Answer (score 0):

You do something like this...

```
<?php
$data = [
    'Bill' => [
        "01" => [
            "Food" => [
                'hamburger' => [
                    'sales' => 210.00,
                    'purchases' => 200.00,
                ],
                'burrito' => [
                    'sales' => 100.00,
                    'purchases' => 40.00,
                ],
            ],
            "Drink" => [
                'coke' => [
                    'sales' => 210.00,
                    'purchases' => 200.00,
                ],
                'pepsi' => [
                    'sales' => 100.00,
                    'purchases' => 40.00,
                ],
            ],
            "total" => [
                'sales' => 620.00,
                'purchases' => 480.00,
            ],
        ]
    ],
    'Ted' => [
        "01" => [
            "Food" => [
                'hamburger' => [
                    'sales' => 110.00,
                    'purchases' => 100.00,
                ],
                'burrito' => [
                    'sales' => 120.00,
                    'purchases' => 40.00,
                ],
            ],
            "Drink" => [
                'coke' => [
                    'sales' => 110.00,
                    'purchases' => 100.00,
                ],
                'pepsi' => [
                    'sales' => 120.00,
                    'purchases' => 40.00,
                ],
            ],
            "total" => [
                'sales' => 460.00,
                'purchases' => 280.00,
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
$finalResults = [];
foreach ($data as $userName => $bills) {
    foreach ($bills as $billIndex => $billParts) {
        if (!array_key_exists($billIndex, $finalResults)) {
            $finalResults[$billIndex] = [
                'total' => [
                    'sales' => 0,
                    'purchases' => 0,
                ]
            ];
        }
        foreach ($billParts as $partIndex => $details) {
            if (!array_key_exists($partIndex, $finalResults[$billIndex])) {
                $finalResults[$billIndex][$partIndex] = [];
            }
            if ($partIndex !== 'total') {
                foreach ($details as $productCode => $productData) {
                    if (!array_key_exists($productCode, $finalResults[$billIndex][$partIndex])) {
                        $finalResults[$billIndex][$partIndex][$productCode] = [
                            'sales' => 0,
                            'purchases' => 0,
                        ];
                    }
                    $finalResults[$billIndex][$partIndex][$productCode]['sales'] += $productData['sales'];
                    $finalResults[$billIndex][$partIndex][$productCode]['purchases'] += $productData['purchases'];
                }
            } else {
                $finalResults[$billIndex][$partIndex]['sales'] += $details['sales'];
                $finalResults[$billIndex][$partIndex]['purchases'] += $details['purchases'];
            }
        }
    }
}
print_r($finalResults);
```